# hierarchical query task with pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql

It's my first question.I have such task in school to do.We have table with columns NAME,PARENT,MONEY,CITY.The task is to produce output names,money and average money of descendants for whom it is true, that the average money
of the descendants is greater than the person's money.

I write this code but can't understand error...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rich_avg_descendant IS
 cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
 FOR rec IN (SELECT name, money,AVG(money) FROM ourtable) loop
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM ourtable 
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING AVG(money)> rec.money
  START WITH name = rec.name CONNECT BY PRIOR name = parent;
  IF cnt > 0 THEN dbms_output.put_line(name,money,AVG(money)); END IF;
END loop;
END;
/
```

Error is in START WITH clause that is START underlined.

```
Error starting at line : 14 in command -
BEGIN rich_avg_descendant(); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object myschoolcode.RICH_AVG_DESCENDANT is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Can you please tell my mistake in this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the exact error message. You could try the query on its own with test values to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The posted error message indicates you have a compilation error. So now you need to tell us what that compilation error is. In SQL\*Plus run `show err` after compiling the code. Or query on `select * from user_errors`. And remember to include this info by **editing your question** and don't post another non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

the connect by clause should be preceding the start with clause